# Sending the same trackback multiple times: bad habit?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, trackback, pingback

I need to develop a custom trackback/pingback module for a page where trackbacks/pingbacks are sent and received. Since I can only hook this code and not change it, I'm limited. There is a hook for processing data right before an article is saved, so that would be a point to parse the content and send track-/pingbacks.

BUT: When an article is saved but still hidden / published later, pinging another blog would not 'work' because the article is not available at the time the ping target checks for its existence. Also, when an article gets updated where the content link is modified, another ping would be sent.

Would it be bad to always send a ping/trackback which results in having multiple ping/trackbacks sent? Do pinged blog systems automatically filter out duplicate track-/pingbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Checked some pingback interfaces and they are actually sorting out multiple calls.